# Sign in with apple user migration invalid_request

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I am transferring my iOS app to another developer account.

On my app, i am using Firebase along with Apple Sign in to sign in my users.
I am following this (uncomplete) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/transferring_your_apps_and_users_to_another_team) to try to manage the Apple Sign in migration.

I am blocked at step 2 : calling the `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/usermigrationinfo` endpoint.

Apple returns a `invalid_request` response, probably because i have no idea what is the `sub` parameter :

[image]

Is it the user ID in the Apple database ? In that case, how can i get it from Firebase ?
I have tried to use the Firebase `User` ID as this parameter but i am getting the `invalid_request` message.

I am really confused about what is going wrong here. Here is my request using Postman :

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Note : i have also tried `sub: (old Team ID)` which is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to know about this question :

- Sign in with Apple migration is not necessary when using Firebase and being the owner of the two Apple Developer accounts
- The `sub` parameter is the user `id` generated by Apple when they first use the Sign in With apple

Comment: Tom3652 can you explain why the migration is not required in this instance?

Comment: Well i have simply change my developer account but my old developer account has the keys to use the Sign in With apple, so it's fine if i let these in Firebase.
In real world situation, you would have revoked the first account keys and migrate your users.